# Pass recycler item from one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have to pass the recycler view item I get from my database to another fragment.

```
public class FragLoad extends Fragment {
EditText g_type;
EditText l_capacity, date, quotation;
Button search;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<RPostLoad> rPostLoads;
SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment source,destination;
private static final String URL_RecyclerLoad="http://192.168.43.38/internship_project/android_web_services/RecyclerLoad.php";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_load, container, false);
    g_type=view.findViewById(R.id.goodstype);
    l_capacity=view.findViewById(R.id.loadCap);
    date=view.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    quotation=view.findViewById(R.id.txtQuotations);
    search=view.findViewById(R.id.postSearch);
    recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.rvload);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rPostLoads=new ArrayList<>();

    source= (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment2);
    destination= (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment1);

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rvLoad();
        }
    });
    return view;

}
private void rvLoad() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("g_type", g_type.getText().toString());
    AndroidNetworking.post("http://192.168.43.38/internship_project/android_web_services/RecyclerLoad.php").addBodyParameter(params).setTag("Login").setPriority(Priority.LOW).build().getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Log.d("TAG", "Response" + response.toString());
                JSONArray array=response.getJSONArray("Data");
                for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                    JSONObject product=array.getJSONObject(i);
                    rPostLoads.add(new RPostLoad(
                            product.getString("owner_name"),
                            product.getString("g_type"),
                            product.getString("truck_cap")
                    ));
                }
                RPostLoadAdp adp=new RPostLoadAdp(getActivity(),rPostLoads);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adp);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ANError anError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Server time out please try          later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
  }
  }
```

Above code is of the class from where I get the recycler item from database and need to send the recycler view item to another fragment. The thing is that I am a beginner at android so I have no idea how to send it. The fragment in which I have to receive the recycler item is empty so i didnt post it here.

Comment: You can use EventBus or RxJava for communicate between fragments and activities.

Comment: What is the name of the variable that you wish to send?

Comment: I have to send the array written in the rvload method

Comment: You can pass data to fragment using `setArguments(Bundle b)` method.

Answer (score 1):

you have one `Activity` one `Fragment` and one `RecyclerView`

and yor `Activity` opens `Fragment` and inside of fragment you implemented the `RecylcerView`

to communicate between your `Activity` and `RecyclerView` you need to have a `Listener`

create this `Interface` (listener) :

```
public interface OnSomeThingHappens {
    public void onEvent(); // you can use some argument for the method
}
```

then in your Activity implement the interface and create a method to your fragment to pass the listener from activity to the fragment and then pass it from fragment to `RecyclerView`'s adapter. your activity will be some thing like this :

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity  implements OnSomeThingHappens{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        YourFragment yourFragment = (YourFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.test_fragment);
        yourFragment.setOnSomeThingListener(this); // this indication the listener that is implemented in ActivityMain
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent() {
        // to do your logic 
    }
}
```

and in your `Fragment` when you implement `RPostLoadAdp` send the listener object adapter to the adapter using a setter method in adapter.

then you will have access to the listener and when you want you can call the `onEvent()` method of listener and in `ActivityMain` the method will be called.
now you can do your logic in this method in `ActivityMain` (send some data to other fragment or ..)
hope this help.